# What index should I create to use ir for searching and sorting?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

PostgreSQL 9.4

I have the following table `stat`:

```
user_id       registration_date        operator_id     value
integer   timestamp without time zone    integer
```

The table is about 22M rows. I need to execute the following query:

```
SELECT user_id, operator_id, COUNT(DISTINCT value)
WHERE registration_date > '2011-11-11 0:0:0'
    AND registration_date < '2011-12-11 0:0:0'
GROUP BY user_id, operator_id
```

The interval is quite short. So, I tried to create index on date

```
CREATE INDEX  ON stat(date, user_id, operator_id)
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX  ON stat(user_id, operator_id, date)
```

but they are not used for sorting. The plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=5376.49..5406.24 rows=1 width=21)
  Group Key: user_id, operator_id
  ->  Sort  (cost=5376.49..5383.92 rows=2974 width=21)
        Sort Key: partner_id, platform_id
        ->  Index Scan using idx on stat  (cost=0.43..5204.91 rows=2974 width=21)
              Index Cond: ((registration_date > '2011-11-11 0:0:0'::timestamp without time zone) AND (registration_date < '2011-12-11 0:0:0'::timestamp without time zone))
```

What indes should I create to use index for both sorting and searching?

Comment: What do you mean "they are not sorting"?  You are not specifying an `ORDER BY` so no sorting is needed.  Indexes to not "sort" the data - they just provide a lookup that _could be_ used for sorting (similar to the index in a book)

Comment: Your query plan has columns that do not exist in your query, and your index has columns which do not exist in our table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the structure of the query, I don't think you can use a simple index for both the `WHERE` and the `GROUP BY`.  The inequalities in the `WHERE` prevent this.

If you are generally looking at months that start on the 11th day, then one solution would be an index on an expression.  Something like this:

```
create index . . . on stat((date_trunc(registration_date - interval '10 day'),
                           'month'), user_id, operator_id)
```

The expression calculates the year-month for a date, given that months start on the 11th.

Then you can use the same expression in the query with equality:

```
SELECT user_id, operator_id, COUNT(DISTINCT value)
WHERE date_trunc(registration_date - interval '10 day', 'month') = '2011-11-01'
GROUP BY user_id, operator_id;
```

This at least makes it possible to take advantage of the index for the query.  I'm not 100% sure that Postgres is going to actually use the index though (worth testing).

Note: you might want to include `value` in the index.  Some databases would use the index for the `count(distinct)` as well; once again, I'm not sure if Postgres would in this case.